# Authorize a client to browse Office365 Graph API

Tags: azure, active-directory, office365

I am trying to develop a webapp to let a user browse his Active Directory contacts.
I have two accounts: one to register the application (developer account) and the other that would be the general user who have access to Office365 (user account).
I have set up a Javascript client following the [Azure AD Graph API documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx).
By now, I am able to prompt the user to login and retrieve an access token, but when I try to make a request, I always get a 401 error.
I am pretty new to Azure, so I don't really understand if the problem is in my application configuration or in my code.
I am able to browse the [Graph API explorer](https://graphexplorer.cloudapp.net/) with my user account, so I don't think he's missing the authorization to access it.
I am really confused.

I try to add all the steps I am doing, hoping someone could point out the error.

**Request 1:**

```
Url: https://login.windows.net/{my tenant id or common (both are working) }/oauth2/authorize

Method: GET

Params:
redirect_uri   // my redirect url, the same I registered in my application. It is just a page that returns the content of the URL
client_id      // my client id
response_type  // code
state          // a random generated string, not required, but reccomanded
resource       // https://graph.windows.net
```

**Response 1:**

```
code           // A long string
state          // The string I sent in the request
session_state  // Another string
```

**Request 2:**

```
Url: https://login.windows.net/{my tenant id or common (both are working) }/oauth2/token

Method: POST

Params:
redirect_uri   // it won't be necessary, but in some post they reccomand to add it
client_id      // my client id
client_secret  // my client secret
code           // the code retrieved from Request 1
grant_type     // authorization_code
state          // a random generated string
resource       // https://graph.windows.net
```

**Response 2:**

```
token_type     // Bearer
access_token   // a long token
id_token       // exploring it with the JWT tool, shows it has the correct app id
refresh_token  // a long code
resource       // the same I sent in the request
scope          // Directory.Read UserProfile.Read
expires_in
expires_on
a couple of other irrelevant keys
```

**Request 3:**

```
Url: https://graph.windows.net/{the domain the logged account belong to}/contacts

Method: GET

Headers:
Authorization: Bearer {the access token retrieved from request 2}

Params:
api-version = 1.5 // The value suggested in the documentation.
```

**Response 3:**

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Authentication_MissingOrMalformed",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "Access Token missing or malformed."
        },
        "values": null
    }
}
```

This is the content of my Access Token:

```
{
 typ: "JWT",
 alg: "RS256",
 x5t: "foofoofoofoo"
}.
{
 aud: "https://graph.windows.net",
 iss: "https://sts.windows.net/<SOMEGUID>/",
 iat: 1418224761,
 nbf: 1418224761,
 exp: 1418228661,
 ver: "1.0",
 tid: "<SOMEGUID>",
 amr: [
  "pwd"
 ],
 idp: "https://sts.windows.net/<SOMEGUID>/",
 email: "myuseremail@contoso.com",
 unique_name: "myuseremail@contoso.com",
 sub: "barbarbarbar",
 altsecid: "<an-id>",
 family_name: "Last Name",
 given_name: "First Name",
 appid: "<MY APP ID>",
 appidacr: "1",
 scp: "Directory.Read UserProfile.Read",
 acr: "1"
}
```

## Answer

So, it looks like user must have the "can consent" authorization to authenticate to his own active directory, and this can be provided just by the administrator.
I posted the same request on the MSDN forum and I got the same answer.
I want sincerely thank @Jason Johnston and @Dan Kershaw since this problem was driving me nut and I would never be able to sort it out without their help.
Unfortunately I can award the bounty to just one of them, so I decided to give it @Jason Johnston for the great patience he had in supporting me in this and another discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe if you actually want to browse the Active Directory, and not just read the authenticated user's profile, you need administrator consent for a web app. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/b08d91fa-6a64-4deb-92f4-f5857add9ed8#BKMK_Graph

If you already knew that, then maybe it's a problem with how you've registered your app or the token itself. Make sure you've selected the appropriate permissions per that link in your app registration. If those look right, then you can check the token. There's a handy little token parser here: http://jwt.calebb.net/. Just paste in the value of your token and it will show you the decoded JSON. Look at the scope or scp parameters.

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "asdfsadfasdfsa"
}

{
  "aud": "https://graph.windows.net/",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/<SOMEGUID>",
  "iat": 1418158549,
  "nbf": 1418158549,
  "exp": 1418162449,
  "ver": "1.0",
  "tid": "<SOMEGUID>",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "oid": "<SOMEGUID>",
  "upn": "admin@contoso.com",
  "unique_name": "admin@contoso.com",
  "sub": "askdljalsdfs",
  "puid": "1003BFFD88937280",
  "family_name": "Administrator",
  "given_name": "MOD",
  "appid": "<YOUR APP ID>",
  "appidacr": "0",
  "scp": "Directory.Read user_impersonation UserProfile.Read",
  "acr": "1"
}
```

Comment: The return scope when I request an access token is `Directory.Read user_impersonation UserProfile.Read`: should it be inside the token_id as well?

Comment: No I don't think so. Try taking out the user_impersonation entry, which is the "Full access to mailbox" permission under Exchange. That permission isn't compatible with the REST apis.

Comment: Same problem: `401 Access Token missing or malformed.`

Comment: Just to be sure, you're putting the token in the Authorization header of your request like "Authorization: Bearer <token>", right?

Comment: Ok. Does the appid parameter of your token match your app? What is the value of the aud parameter?

Comment: yes, it does. the app-id in the id_token is the same as the client_id of my request.

Comment: Ok. I played with this a bit, doing the same request that you're doing. I had to add back the user_impersonation permission to get it to work, otherwise I got a 403 Forbidden (can you tell I'm an Exchange guy, not an AD guy?). In any event, take the entire value that you're putting after "Bearer" in the Authorization header, and past it in that token parser. It should resemble the structure I've added to my original answer.

Comment: It has some different field, but it looks more or less the same.

Comment: The differences might be important, especially since the error indicates the token is missing or malformed. The field values will of course be different, but the field names should all be the same. However, another thing to check would be to use Fiddler or some other network sniffer to see the actual request going to graph.windows.net, and confirming that the token value actually going on the wire is correct.

Comment: I posted the content of my token. `oid`, `upn` and `puid` are missing, but I have `email` and `idp`. I also checked if the Headers are sent correctly, and they actually are.

Comment: I am now checking the correct syntax [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn195587.aspx).

Comment: Odd. Are you signing in with an Office 365 tenant organization account? I've asked some Azure guys to look at your token, maybe they'll have an idea of what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

The token you've pasted is missing the OID and UPN, and that'll probably be why you are seeing this error.  I'll have to go back and check how this access token could have been issued without those claims.

Comment: Are they both required? How is it possible that the server returns me an incomplete token? That's what really confuses me.

Comment: Same here.  I'm not sure how this is happening.  Will need to involve a few other folks.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  Are you using ADAL to acquire the access token?  If so, can you share that code snippet please?  We suspect that you are configuring the STS URL (iss that shows up in the token) with the tenantId of where your app is registered (developer tenant).  In effect, no matter what tenant the user is coming from, you are always trying to sign them in using your developer tenant, and those users do not exist in the developer tenant.  Can you try using the common endpoint rather than a tenant specific endpoint? Do tid and iss match? idp and altsecid shouldn't be present

Comment: So, here is the behavior: if I try to run the request to the common endpoint BEFORE login, I am redirect to user login and after the login I receive an error saying I am not an administrator. If I redo the request using my developer endpoint instead of the common one, I get the Auth Code. If I then re-redo the request with the common endpoint, I get the Auth Code. The token retrieved with this code has iss, tid, idp and altsecid. tid and iss match.

Comment: I have never realized that running the first request on common endpoint was rising an error.

Comment: When you do the common endpoint and receive an error that you are not an admin, are you logging on with a tenant admin account? You have to be an admin to read directory data. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/b08d91fa-6a64-4deb-92f4-f5857add9ed8#BKMK_Graph

Comment: Jason is correct.  I see from a similar post on MSDN forums that you only need to read the signed in user's profile.  If that's true, you don't need "Read Directory Data".  Removing this required permission will mean that users can consent to this app. Can you either make this change, or try the user consent with an admin user from your "customer" tenant, when requesting the code from the common endpoint.